# Netbeans shows blank why?

Tags: hibernate, netbeans

I tried to dive into the source code of Hibernate, noticed some methods are invoked without any source code like initLockers, and postConstruct(mapping) in SingleTableEntityPersister. Is this normal? Btw, i was using Netbeans.

Comment: You need to provide additional information: [1] Update your post to state the versions of Hibernate, NetBeans and Java that were used. [2] Update your post with a description of the actions you took to step into the Hibernate code, including a screen shot showing the problem.

Comment: i tried it earlier, the blank issue has gone! weird...